# Neural Network implementation for Number Recognition in Java

Tags: java

Firstly, i should mention that i only recently started programming (about a year ago). My main-language is Java.

to elaborate on what I've done:

- to learn about Neural Networks i watched 3Blue1Brown´s series on the topic
- after (mostly) understanding it i started to make the actual Implementation

I implemented a File-Reader to turn the raw numbers of the Database (i used MNIST just like 3b1b) into three arrays : 1 for the labels, 1 for the Images and one for the grayscale-values (i mapped the RGB values between 0 and 1) in one input-array

I then designed a test() and train() method, this is what i did:

```
public class Network {
    int L;
    int[] Lsize;
    double[][][] weights;
    double[][] biases;

    public Network(int... Lsize) {
        L = Lsize.length;
        this.Lsize = Lsize;
        weights = new double[L - 1][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {

            weights[i] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]][Lsize[i]];

            for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {

                for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {

                    weights[i][j][k] = (Math.random() * 2) - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        biases = new double[L - 1][];
        for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {

            biases[i] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]];
            for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {

                biases[i][j] = (Math.random() * 2) - 1;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Network n = new Network(28 * 28, 16, 16, 10);
        Database mnist_train = new Database(60000, 28, 28, "mnist_train");
        Database mnist_test = new Database(10000, 28, 28, "mnist_test");
        System.out.println("accuracy= " + n.accuracy(mnist_test));
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i ++) {
        n.train(mnist_train, 10, 0.1);
        System.out.println("accuracy= " + n.accuracy(mnist_test));
        }
    }

    public void train(Database data,int batchsize,double factor) {
        Batch[] batches = data.dividetoBatches(batchsize);

        for (int b = 0; b < data.n / batchsize; b++) {
            System.out.println("Step " + b + " started!");
            
            Batch batch = batches[b];
            double[][][] averagegweights = new double[L - 1][][];
            double[][] averagegbiases = new double[L - 1][];
            for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
                averagegweights[i] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]][Lsize[i]];
                averagegbiases[i] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]];
            }
            double averagecost = 0;

            
            for (int e = 0; e < batchsize; e++) {
                double[] target = batch.target[e];
                double[] values = batch.values[e];

                double[][] z = new double[L - 1][];
                double[][] a = new double[L][];
                a[0] = values;

                
                for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
                    a[i + 1] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]];
                    z[i] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]];
                    
                    for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                        double sum = biases[i][j];
                        
                        for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                            sum += weights[i][j][k] * a[i + 1][j];
                        }
                        z[i][j] = sum;
                        a[i + 1][j] = sigmoid(sum);
                    }
                }

                double[][][] gweights = new double[L - 1][][];
                double[][] gbiases = new double[L - 1][];

                double[][] dCa = new double[L][];
                double cost = 0;
                dCa[L - 1] = new double[Lsize[L - 1]];
                for (int i = 0; i < Lsize[L - 1]; i++) {
                    dCa[L-1][i] = 2 * (target[i] - a[L - 1][i]);
                    cost += (target[i] - a[L - 1][i]) * (target[i] - a[L - 1][i]);
                }
                


                // Backpropagation:
                for (int i = L - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                    dCa[i] = new double[Lsize[i]];
                    gweights[i] = new double[Lsize[i+1]][Lsize[i]];
                    gbiases[i] = new double[Lsize[i]];

                    for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                        gbiases[i][j] = dsigmoid(z[i][j]) * dCa[i+1][j];

                        for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                            gweights[i][j][k] = a[i][k] * dsigmoid(z[i][j]) * dCa[i+1][j];
                        }
                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                        dCa[i][k] = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                            dCa[i][k] += weights[i][j][k] * dsigmoid(z[i][j]) * dCa[i + 1][j];
                        }
                    }

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                        averagegbiases[i][j] += gbiases[i][j];
                        for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                            averagegweights[i][j][k] += gweights[i][j][k];
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                averagecost += cost;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                    averagegbiases[i][j] = averagegbiases[i][j]/batchsize * -1;
                    for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                        averagegweights[i][j][k] = averagegweights[i][j][k]/batchsize * -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                    biases[i][j] += averagegbiases[i][j] * factor;
                    for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                        weights[i][j][k] += averagegweights[i][j][k] * factor;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            averagecost = averagecost/batchsize;
                
            System.out.println("averagecost = " + averagecost);
            
//          System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(batch.target));
            
            System.out.println("Das sollte eine" + data.labels[0] + " sein!");
            
            data.shuffle();
            
            double[] output = test(data.values[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                float val = (float) output[i];
                System.out.print(i + ":    ");
                System.out.printf("%.2f", val);
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("Step " + b + " finished!");
        }
    }
    
    public double accuracy(Database data) {
        int rightanswers = 0;
        int answers = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
            if(maxIndex(test(data.values[i])) == data.labels[i]) {
                rightanswers++;
                
            }
            answers++;
        }
        return (double)rightanswers/(double)answers;
        
    }
    
    public int maxIndex(double[] output) {
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            if(output[i] > output[index])
                index = i;
        }
        return index;
    }

    public double[] test(double[] input) {
        double[][] values = new double[L][];
        values[0] = input;

        for (int i = 0; i < L - 1; i++) {
            values[i + 1] = new double[Lsize[i + 1]];
            for (int j = 0; j < Lsize[i + 1]; j++) {
                double sum = biases[i][j];
                for (int k = 0; k < Lsize[i]; k++) {
                    sum += weights[i][j][k] * values[i][k];
                }
                values[i + 1][j] = sigmoid(sum);
            }
        }

        double[] output = values[L - 1];
        return output;
    }
    
    

    public double sigmoid(double x) {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, x));
    }

// derivative of the sigmoid-function
    public double dsigmoid(double x) {
        return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x));
    }

}
```

my problem now is when i run the training the Cost-function decreases, but only because all of the output-values are nearing 0 and not because the network has actually found the right number to the picture.
after about one run through the Database the average Cost stagnates around 0.9
am i missing something fundamental or am i just not noticing an simple error

Thank you in advance

I`m sorry for my bad English, I´m actually German

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: i accidentally posted this before actually finishing the question

Comment: what relevance, if any, does the code have to your question? please remove all code not absolutely required to help describe or isolate your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is to increase the complexity of the network. I just tried your architecture with my implementation and the network you currently have definitely isn't big enough to fit handwritten digits. I would recommend 784,128,128,10 as that had around 90% accuracy for 3 runs over the training set. If that doesn't yield better results, make sure your implementation of a neural network is functional on something less complex like the XOR problem. If XOR is learnable by your implementation, it could be the way you are altering the dataset. Debugging a neural network is tough, but you have to make sure the foundation of it is built correctly before looking at higher-level problems like learning rate and optimizers. You're using vanilla gradient descent so you should definitely implement momentum as it is easier to implement than what you've already done and is a significant improvement to your current method.